# Object is not refreshing in mobile browser

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have simple button

```
<div class="btn red-btn" role="button">1</div>
```

and after click on this button I do something like that:

```
if flag
   this.$el.find("div").attr("class", "btn blue-btn");
else 
   this.$el.find("div").attr("class", "btn red-btn");
```

I mean, when I click on this button, it changes color. Everything is ok, when I click for the first time, but after second click, it doesn't change color. 
 1. On desktop browser it works perfectly, but in mobile browser it doesn't.
 2. When I click in other place of the page, button is changing it color after second click. It looks like it is not refreshing after second click and when I click other place it is refreshing.

Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you call the button's click event?

Comment: Please, also add your code with button event's.